# second click on a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, click

i've got some problem, when i click on a button, 'toolbar' append to body, and when i click on a button again, 'toolbar' append to body one more time. How to remove repeated event when I click on a button? huge thx!

```
var Link = function(collection, el){
    el.on('mouseup', function(e){
        $('[el-button]').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
        });

        var _toolbar = new Toolbar({link: el});
        var toolbar  = _toolbar.render();
        toolbar.addClass('in');
        $('body').prepend(toolbar);

        toolbar.css({
            left: el.offset().left,
            top: el.offset().top - toolbar.height() - 10  
        });

        setTimeout(function(){
            $(document).on('mouseup', function(e){
                if($(e.target).closest(toolbar).length == 0){
                    $(el).unbind('click', arguments.callee);
                        toolbar.removeClass('in');
                        toolbar.remove();
                }
            });
        }, 100);
    });

    el.bind('linkChange', function(){
        var section = el.parents('section');
        var index   = section.index();
        var model   = collection.at(index);
        model.set(Helper.sectionToObj(section))
    });
}

return Link;
```

how it works now: http://take.ms/b5giM

Comment: You only want the handler to fire once?

Answer (score 3):

Try `.one()` - it executes only once. [jQuery documentation for one](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

```
el.one('mouseup', function(e){
```

Comment: nice and simple  solution +1 , more better than mine

Comment: @evan no, if i use "one", this works 'once' and i need to reload page every time.

Comment: @Maks what do you mean with reloading?

Comment: @Mouser if i use '.one', this works only one time! i mean to function worked again I need to reload the page.

Comment: @Maks Aha, you want the content of the function to change. First click append toolbar, second click reload.

Answer (score 0):

This question already have a good answer from  Evan , this is another method

try something like this,

```
$(".idofbutton").click(function(){
    //your work 


    // after finishing your work unbind the click handler for only this button
    $(this).unbind('click');
}
```

Comment: this solution also does not solve my problem, but thx for try

Comment: try to put this code inside   click event $(this).find('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled','disabled');

Comment: no, because user can edit button when toolbar appended, i can add 'disabled' to the button.

Answer (score 0):

Based upon the answers and comments on the page I would suggest this:

```
el.mouseup(function(e){
    $('[el-button]').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    if (($this).prev(".in").length == 0) {

    var _toolbar = new Toolbar({link: el});
    var toolbar  = _toolbar.render();
    toolbar.addClass('in');
    $('body').prepend(toolbar);

    toolbar.css({
        left: el.offset().left,
        top: el.offset().top - toolbar.height() - 10  
    });

    setTimeout(function(){
        $(document).on('mouseup', function(e){
            if($(e.target).closest(toolbar).length == 0){
                $(el).unbind('click', arguments.callee);
                    toolbar.removeClass('in');
                    toolbar.remove();
            }
        });
    }, 100);
   }
});
```

The element Toolbar has a class name called `in`. I don't know the further mark up of that element, so you can change that. If there is an previous sibling on the page (before element `el`) with class name `in` do not execute the code.

Comment: i DONT need to reload page, I only need to prevent the event to the next click on the 'el'

Comment: @Maks "*this works only one time! i mean to function worked again I need to reload the page*". Then what is the meaning of this comment?

Comment: @Maks Fine, I get it. See my updated answer should sooth your needs. However it's a variant on the answer of Arunprashanth.

Comment: no. it works only after first click, after second it's never working again. look: http://take.ms/6p6c2

Comment: @Maks What do I need to see. You're clicking on the page and indeed nothing happens, but WHAT needs to happen. You're being to vague for us to give a correct answer.

Comment: oh god. i need to click on the element and toolbar APPEND, click to body toolbar REMOVE, click on the element again, toolbar APPEND again ( this all works fine ), but if i click on element, when toolbar appended, i need to nothing is going to happen!

Comment: @Maks Wow, and how could we deduce that from your original question?

Comment: see my question: "How to remove repeated event when I click on a button"

Comment: @Maks; Maybe it should've been something like: How can I prevent the element from firing when the toolbar is already present.

Comment: don't know why, but no, if i click on element again, it's append again, change this:

 `toolbar.addClass('in');`

to this: 

`setTimeout(function(e){toolbar.addClass('in');},100);` and you will see that it's not working: http://take.ms/pmIPx :(